# How to create sequence in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python

hello guys I have data in the following format :

```
User touchpoint conversion
A     C1            0
A     C2            0
A     C1            0
A     C4            1
A     C2            0
A     C1            0
A     C1            0
A     C1            1
```

I was able to create the sequences using the following code :

```
df1 = df.groupby('User')[['touchpoint']].aggregate(lambda x: tuple(x)).reset_index()

df1['channel_path'] = df1['touchpoint'].apply(lambda x: '>'.join(x))
```

However I want to split the sequences into sub sequences when I encounter conversion value 1 eg:

```
sequence 1 : C1>C2>C1>C4
sequence 2: C2>C1>C1>C1
```

using the current code I get the whole sequence:

```
C1>C2>C1>C4>C2>C1>C1>C1
```

Any pointers in this regard would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using another approach.Your df1 has all the combination since you are not specifying the break point.

Try this..

```
l = [i for i in range(len(data)) if data['conversion'][i] == 1]
pointer = 0
for pos in l:
    print('>'.join(data['touchpoint'][pointer:pos+1]))
    pointer = pos+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'User': ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B', 'B'],
                 'touchpoint': ['C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C4', 'C2', 'C1', 'C1', 'C1'],
                    'conversion': [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]})

df1 = df.groupby(['User']).aggregate(lambda x: list(x))
df1 = df1.apply(lambda x: "".join([x[1][i] + '*' if value else x[1][i] + '>' for i, value in enumerate(x[0])]), axis = 1)
df1 = df1.apply(lambda x: x.split('*')[:-1])
```

You just add a special character, say `*`, to indicate the position to split at.

**Output**

```
User
A    [C1>C2>C1>C4]
B    [C2>C1>C1>C1]
dtype: object
```

which is a series object with index User